# Group a range towards a range

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, group-by

I have a table:

```
tblUnit (ID, Name, PriceFrom, PriceTo)

1, Audi, 170, 340
2, BMW,  250, 290
3, Ford, 275, 500
4, Kia,  110, 250
5, VW,   135, 460
```

And then I have predefined price ranges like this:

```
tblPriceRange(ID, PriceFrom, PriceTo)

1,   0,  100
2, 100,  200
3, 200,  300
4, 300,  400
5, 400, 1000
```

I am trying to count the number of vehicles that exists within one or more price ranges. BMW is only in 1 range, while Audi is in 3 ranges and Ford is in 3.

The result I am after should look something like this:

```
VehiclesPerRange:
(RangeFrom, RangeTo, NoVehicles)
  0, 100,  0
100, 200,  3
200, 300,  5
300, 400,  3
400, 1000, 2
```

I have read through lots of posts on this forum and elsewhere about grouping by a range. But those examples are focused on 1 single price that should be grouped towards a range. I understand how to do this via a join etc., but I cant figure out how to write SQL to group a range towards a range.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to join `tblUnit` with `tblPriceRange` matching rows where the ranges overlap. Two ranges overlap if the begin of the second is before the end of the first and the begin of the first before the end of the second, so your join condition would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.tblUnit u
JOIN dbo.tblPriceRange p
ON u.PriceFrom < p.PriceTo
AND p.PriceFrom < u.PriceTo
```

After that you just have to group and count:

```
SELECT PriceFrom, PriceTo, COUNT(1)
FROM(
    SELECT p.PriceFrom, p.PriceTo
    FROM dbo.tblUnit u
    JOIN dbo.tblPriceRange p
    ON u.PriceFrom < p.PriceTo
    AND p.PriceFrom < u.PriceTo
)X
GROUP BY PriceFrom, PriceTo;
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution Sebastian! There are things you can do with JOIN that I am not fully aware of so far.. Thanks!

Comment: +1 and, of course, subselecting is unnecessary. Modifying the first query like this, `SELECT p.PriceFrom, p.PriceTo, COUNT(*) FROM ... GROUP BY p.PriceFrom, p.PriceTo`, would do just fine.

Comment: @TwisterX, if you want to learn more about JOINs, check out my blog series here: http://sqlity.net/en/1146/a-join-a-day-introduction/