# Count records by groups while drilling down in the recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by

I am working on a website which has a drill down feature for a large recordset.

Lets say I have the following recordset:

```
tblBrand (ID, Name, PriceFrom, PriceTo, BHPFrom, BHPTo)

1, Audi, 170000, 340000, 100, 250
2, BMW,  250000, 290000, 110, 400
3, Ford, 275000, 500000,  75, 150
4, Kia,  110000, 250000,  50, 100
5, VW,   135000, 460000,  50, 200
```

To the user I will by default show all records. And in my drill down feature, I am presenting to the user URLs like this:

```
Price:
0-100000 (0 brands)
100000-200000 (3 brands)
200000-300000 (5 brands)
300000-> (3 brands)

BHP:
0-100 (3 brands)
100-200 (5 brands)
200-> (3 brands)
```

So far so good. I got the solution to the count-by-ranges problem here: [Group a range towards a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564544/group-a-range-towards-a-range)

But my problem occurs when the user clicks on one of my drill-down links. Lets say he clicks on "BHP 0-100". Then it will only be tblBrand ID 3,4,5 to be displayed. This is of-course easy with a simple WHERE clause. But here is my question:

**How do I present to the user an updated count of Brands per Price-range and Brands per BHP-range after the user has done the first drill-down by selecting "BHP 0-100"?**

Currently my solution (which works) is to insert the resulting recordset after the drill down into a temp-table and do all the new counting on that table. This is an easy way, but with 100k+ records and +/- 20 types of drill down possibilities each having 5-20 ranges, it becomes a very heavy task!

UPDATE: This is what I am doing (**pseudecode**):

```
SELECT INTO #DrillDownRecordset (ID, Name)
FROM tblBrand
WHERE BHPFrom > @SelBHPFrom AND BHPTo < @SelBHPTo

SELECT COUNT (ID)
FROM #DrillDownRecordset
GROUP BY PriceRanges

SELECT COUNT (ID)
FROM #DrillDownRecordset
GROUP BY BHPRanges
```

This works, but is very heavy..

Could I be looking at using ROLLUP?

Comment: I think you are looking for **GROUP BY** clause. Show us what you have tried??

Comment: Use a WHERE IN (brand_id1,brand_id2) to your original query.

Comment: Just updated the question with some pseudo-code to illustrate my current method.